# Maintain Navigation stack of Response.Redirect in a asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, session, redirect

I want to set a session variable value before response.redirect and in that session variable I would like to store the page url to which I am redirecting to.

So that from page where I am redirected I cao n redirect user back to its last page.

I tried Urlreferer property too but I am always getting destination page url in that property not the orginating page URL.

I have added handler to Application_EndRequest but when I tried to set session variable value in that session is set as nothing in that.

So I might need to trap a event after Response.Redirect but before session end.

So please help me to achieve that.

Comment: urlreferer will get the previous page url

Comment: As I mentioned its containing the destination page url only so suppose I redirect from A.aspx to B.aspx. But on B.aspx when I checl urlreferrer I expect A.aspx url but its showing B.aspx not sure what is overriding that.

Comment: please refer this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Could you post your code where you are using UrlReferrer.

Comment: I tried both:  Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri) and  Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()) thats why I planned to keep it in session variable

Comment: Actually I am doing Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri) on click of a "Done" button and that done button raises a postback and thats why I am seeing the same page URL on click of that button which makes sense.

Comment: Now what I can do is save the urlreferer at page load of all those page where I want user to get back to the urlreferer but since there many page I feel if I can tap any central event which triggers after any Response.Redirect and I can set the urlreferrer so that I dont have do it on all the pages. Any idea?

Comment: Yeah you can achieve that,on page load itself load the value of the Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() in a session variable and make sure you check IsPostBack.If PostBack is false i.e some other control has initiated to process whole page life cycle again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have two pages A.aspx and B.aspx
In the OnClick of button in Page A you are initiating a Response.Redirect to Page B.aspx as follows.

```
Response.Redirect("B.aspx");
```

Now in the the page_load event of B.aspx if Page is loaded for the first time then take the Request.UrlReferrer variable in a session variable.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (!IsPostBack)
       {
         Session["PreviousPage"] = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
       }
  }
```

Now even if the page life cycle is triggered with any asp control since it is not a fresh postback then u would not take wrong value in your session in this case.
Hope this helps.